# Internet Explorer "mixed content" warning -- how to squelch?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a Facebook application(meaning it's required to be HTTPS) and the client reported back that in IE, ugly "mixed content" warnings are popping up. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx

Now, the reason these are popping up is because I'm loading some images from a CDN that I don't control. The CDN only supports HTTP -- no HTTPS. But my application requires HTTPS because it's a Facebook app(and it's just good practice).

So I feel like I'm between a rock and a hard place... obviously these "mixed content" warnings aren't favorable, but I can't change the CDN to support HTTPS.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Saw this: http://digital.bigfish.co.uk/2012/04/avoiding-mixed-content-with-ssl/ but its proposed solution negates the value of using a geographically spread CDN and puts more bandwidth requirements on my application. Don't care for it :(